# Bootstrap accordion won't expand on one page

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-accordion

On my index page I use the example code from getbootstrap.com, and now I want to use it again on a different page of the same site. It shows up just fine, but is non-responsive and wont expand/collapse.

The header content for the two pages is exactly the same - literally copy/pasted. I'm not a pro at coding - any ideas? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet-search.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-white bg-white">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="images/white_logo_color_background.jpg" alt="" width="170" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
        </a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-text">
          <li class="nav=item">
            <a class="nav-link active text-secondary fontstyles" area-current="page" href="index.php">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav=item">
            <a class="nav-link text-secondary fontstyles" href="searchreziworks.php"><strong>Search ReziWorks</strong></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav=item">
            <a class="nav-link text-secondary fontstyles" href="createprofile.php">Be a prototype user</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav=item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark fontstyles" href="becomepartner.php">Become a partner company</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
          <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Accordion Item #1
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            Accordion Item #2
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            Accordion Item #3
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I forgot to put the JS/popper script at the end of the page.

Comment: As a side note Chris, if you use the Bootstrap 5 Bundle JS, Popper is included. The way you have called Bootstrap to your page assume no Popper and then you have added popper. You could have the entire lot by adding the one line for Bootstrap Bundle. It's all in the Docs. Good work on digging out the answer by the way.